# Connecting two APs of different models to SXT router

Tags: router, access-point, wireless-bridge

In my small business office I have a SXT lite router that is connected to Internet and then a TP-LINK TD-W8960N router is connected to the SXT wired as AP.
Now I need to extend the internal wireless network using a TP-LINK TD-W8151N router, but it seems they can not be matched together. Although I tried to set them to the same situation, as far as my laptop sometimes connect to other AP unwanted. Notice that both APs work well and they worked with similar model of each other. Do you think that am I able to do the stuff or they can not work together at all? Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to serverfault.  We review all first posts to help new users.  Your question is a little unclear.  It would help if you were more specific about "Although I tried to set them to the same situation, as far as my laptop sometimes connect to other AP unwanted. "  
Are you saying that they are the same SSID, same IP range?  Please expand your question.  Diagrams also help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes exactly that means I changed all the settings that could show both APs are the same network, like IP range, SSID, pre-shared key, channel number etc. And due to the similarity my laptop suddenly connected to the second AP while it was connected to the main AP. I hope I could've been more clear.

Comment: Any idea dear Scott Lundberg?